# Mutex in getter setter

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering about how to use mutex for multithreaded application. Do my getters need to lock too? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252452/does-a-getter-function-need-a-mutex) post. The answer is yes, I need to guard getters functions
but that means I'll be able to perform one read at a time, and I wonder if it could be improved.

[T.E.D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252452/does-a-getter-function-need-a-mutex/2252737#2252737) suggests that you can implement locks in a way that many threads can read the data at the same time if setters' functions didnt lock the mutex to perform a write.
I tried to find some examples - reading Qt's documentation - tought, QMutex doesn't have a isLocked() function or something like this. So how can you praticly implements this kind of "intelligent's locks'.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a special kind of locking mechanism called [readers-writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock). With this lock any number of readers can access the resource simultaneously, but for a writer to have access all reader threads must block.

Looks like Qt has a [QReadWriteLock](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qreadwritelock.html) class that implements this mechanism.

Comment: Well it seems I didn't search well enough. Thank you !

Comment: please read this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659295/why-c0x-standard-committee-rejected-boostshared-mutex) about reader-writer mutex

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to synchronize access to your getters, not to *lock* them in common sence since they don't modify anything, but to put a [memory barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) implicitly. So multithreaded operations will be put in right order and your getters will won't read partially modified data.

You don't need any intelligent locks, because reader-writer mutex [won't provide you any benefit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659295/why-c0x-standard-committee-rejected-boostshared-mutex).