# Multi-thread singleton: does the instance method need a mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, mutex

I have a configuration of my application stored in a singleton class, like this (simplified):

```
class Conf
{
    Conf();
    Conf(const Conf&);
    Conf& operator=(const Conf&);
    ~Conf();

public:

    static Conf& instance() 
    {
        static Conf singleton;
        return singleton;
    };

    static void setProperty(const std::string& name,
                            const std::string& value);
    static std::string getProperty(const std::string& name);

private:

    QMutex _mutex;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> _properties;
};
```

Because the configuration class can be accessed from many threads, I use mutex for synchronization:

```
void Conf::setProperty(const std::string& name,
                 const std::string& value)
{
    QMutexLocker(&Conf::instance()._mutex);
    Conf::instance()._properties[name]=value;
}

std::string Conf::getProperty(const std::string& name)
{
    QMutexLocker(&Conf::instance()._mutex);
    return Conf::instance()._properties[name];
}
```

Does the `Conf::instance()` method also need a lock?

I have found similar question: [does a getter function need a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252452/does-a-getter-function-need-a-mutex), 
but in my case there is no setter method (lets assume that the instance of the singleton is created before the threads start).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using c++11 or better the creation of the static singleton is guaranteed to be thread safe.

If you're still using c++03 then you need to provide your own mechanism.

by request:

section 6.7 of the c++11 standard:

> such a variable is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization. [...] If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.

footnote:

> The implementation must not introduce any deadlock around execution of the initializer.

Comment: Can you give a reference to your assertion of automatic thread safety for C++11.

Comment: @doron lots to learn here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration 
in particular look for the heading "Static local variables" and what happens if an exception is thrown during the initialisation.

Answer (score 3):

in C++11 `instance()` does not need mutex, in C++98 it does as two threads might enter it at once an start constructing object. C++11 ensures single initialization of `static` 'local' variables.

Comment: If I have assumed that the instance of the singleton is created before the threads start, there is no need to lock?

Comment: @user2449761 the singleton is created the first time that control flows over its definition. i.e. the first time `Conf::instance()` is called

Answer (score 2):

Used this way no, instance() does not need a mutex.

However I would enforce this by moving instance in the private section allowing client code to use just setProperty/getProperty.